# What is the difference between 'end' and 'end as'

Tags: sql, conditional-operator

Simple question. I noticed it seems I can use them interchangeably, but I wasn't sure if they were the exact same command. I searched online and couldn't find anything? Here an example query that gives me the same result:

```
select 
case when ID in ('1', '2', '3')
then 'Jack'
else 'Jim'
end as Person
from Table.Names

select
case when ID in ('1', '2', '3')
then 'Jack'
else 'Jim'
end Person
from Table.Names
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `as` in the statement is aesthetic. It tells the compiler that you are setting a name.

Comment: SQL assumes `as` if it is omitted.

Answer (score -1):

END is the marker that closes the CASE expression. You must have exactly one END statement for every CASE Statement. The AS marker is used to introduce an alias.